# Rendering objects by category in Django

Tags: django

I created a model, in which admin categorizes posts by being new or exclusive. Now I want to view posts, that are only new. here's the code:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    class Category(models.TextChoices):
        NEW = 'NP', ('New Post')
        EXCLUSIVE = 'EP', ('Exclusive Post')


    post_category = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=Category.choices,
        default=Category.NEW,
    )
    title = models.CharField('Title of the post',max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField('Page content', max_length=500)
    posted = models.DateTimeField('last updated')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    
    def is_new(self):
        return self.post_category in{
            self.Category.NEW,
            self.Category.EXCLUSIVE,
        }
```

views:

```
def index(request):
    post_list = Post.objects.filter(post_category).order_by('-posted')[:2]
    context = {
        'post_list': post_list,
        'page_list': Pages.objects.all(),

    }

    return render(request, 'pages/extension.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
post_list = Post.objects.filter(post_category=Post.Category.NEW)
```

Comment: Kowalinski it worked but in a little different way. I tried post_category = Post.Category.NEW. thanks anyways.

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right. I've forgotten it's an inner class, but great you've made it working